# Cloning server (Linux) environment on my local (Windows) machine using Docker

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel, docker, virtual-machine

I would like to clone my server environment running MySQL v5.7 on a Linux machine to my local Windows machine. I am currently running MySQL 8.0 and I'm experiencing few issues when duplicating the database and using it on my Laravel project, hence, my thought on using Docker to fix this. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Hi amrod92, can you please explain what issues you are running into? Naturally, we cannot assist with a problem we are unaware of. It is entirely likely that it does not like the jump from 5.7 to 8 and you need to take a few intermediary steps. Also, can please you detail the steps you are taking to move the database over?

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your reply. The project uses rely on stored procedures to call the database, my colleague was able to create it on his Windows machine using MySQL 8.0 without any issue and deploy this on the live Linux server running MySQL 5.7. When I duplicate the database to use it on my environment I got the below issues.

Comment: This is the issue: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'xxxx.sites.site_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: call spsStoreFootfallTodayByRegionID(24)) {"userId":693,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'xxx.sites.site_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: call spsStoreFootfallTodayByRegionID(24)) at vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:669)

Comment: My idea was to use Docker as a way to create a virtual Linux container with MySQL 5.7 on it and call it from the Laravel's .env file but I not sure if this is feasible.

Comment: Given that this includes a stored procedure greatly increases the complexity of the problem. Have you checked that the stored procedure is on the MySQL server on which you are trying to run this? At this point, I am a little out of my depth as I'm unfarmiliar with stored procedures, however have a look at this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-status.html which should help determine whether the procedure exists.